# website not working in chrome but working in IE , firefox

Tags: django

i m facing a peculiar problem, i have a django powered site , which works fine on local host in firefox,IE  and google chrome.When i put it on server it works fine on firefox,IE but not on chrome
The problem is that each time i login in chrome , and try to visit other pages, to redirects me to login page, which means that session variables arent stored or may be some other problem
such thing doesnt happen in mozilla firefox and IE

it would be very grateful if some one could guide me cause i m stuck up and the site needs to be ready in a week

if i m not specific please ask for specifications

thanks for help in advance

```
this is the .htaccess files
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/shaastra
AuthUserFile /home/shaastra/public_html/2011/erp/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "This area is closed for now."
Require valid-user
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /2011/erp$
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(django.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./django.fcgi/erp/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: have you tried on other Chrome? have you watched the cookies?

Comment: in windows chrome i get redirected randomly , i mean i keep on surfing between pages and suddenly i am in redirected to login page.

Comment: it would be helpful , if you could suggest some debugging techniques for this problem

Comment: @user803072 Have you solved this? I have similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea the source of the problem, it could be GC, or maybe your settings, there are one option to set the age of the session maybe forcing this will help you.

```
# settings.py

# 25 minutes
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 150000

# if you whant to be 25 minutes of inactivity you should add this
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

In this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8155)  `Random session timeouts when setting request.set_expiry(0)`  they said:

> I've not seen this happen, personally. A couple things to
>   double-check:
>
> ```
> * Is your session backend evicting sessions for some reason? If
> ```
>
> you're using memcached, this could be the case.
>       * Do you have some sort of intermediary proxy interfering? The
>   fact that varying KeepAlive changes the behavior strongly points to a
>   proxy or something else external to Django.
>
> I suspect that this isn't a Django bug: the fact that modifying
>   Apache's conf changes the behvior strongly points to a web server
>   and/or proxy configuration problem. Changing these parameters in
>   theory shouldn't affect Django at all.